# Joomla 2.5 database $query->where warning

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have this simple code to select custom string from database:

```
protected function getListQuery()
{

              $db = JFactory::getDBO();
              $query = $db->getQuery(true);

              $query->select('*')
                    ->from('#__person');

              $name = 'tom';

              $query->where('name LIKE %'.$db->quote($name).'%');

              return $query;
}
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in xxx\public\libraries\joomla\database\database\mysql.php on
>   line 293

If I remove **where** call, so everything goes ok. Can I debug the datase query? I would like to see whats the final query goes to MySQL server.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I put for example $query->where('id=3'); It also works fine. But does not work with strings.

Comment: I found how to debug queries: echo nl2br(str_replace('#__','prefix_',$query));die;

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will put 
WHERE 'name' LIKE %'tom'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to work this for me:

```
protected function getListQuery()
{

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('*')
          ->from('#__person');

    $name = 'tom';

    $name = $db->Quote('%'.$db->escape($name, true).'%');
    $query->where($db->nameQuote('name').' LIKE '.$name);


    //debug the query  
    // echo nl2br(str_replace('#__','prefix_',$query)); die;

    return $query;
```

}

Comment: Yes because now you are quoting to get 'tom%' instead of 'tom'%.